# How do you read a file then output the integers as '1' in txt

Tags: python

I am trying to open a txt file 
eg.txt contains

```
    1234 then return '1','2','3','4'
    5678             '5','6','7','8'
```

I have tried using str to plus together it seems like the '' just dissappears.

```
 with open('a.txt') as if1:
    for everyline in if1:
        everylineactual = everyline.rstrip('\n')
        for i in everylineactual:
            a= str(i)
            with open('b.txt','a') as of:
                of.write('"')
                of.write(a)
```

Comment: Erm P.S. to all It was because I was trying to go to the format screen first but it end up actually submitting a question

Comment: Well, you could hit a delete button temporarily... Question looked like a spam for almost 5 minutes. Be careful next time!

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: If the indentation is at all correct (there are certainly syntax errors here in any event) you are overwriting everything except the last letter of output. You should make sure the indentation is *exactly* as in your real code; on the desktop version of the site, you can paste your code, then paint it with the cursor and type ctrl-K to have it properly formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

Input file:

```
1234
5678
```

Code:

```
with open('a.txt') as if1:
    for everyline in if1:
        everylineactual = everyline.rstrip('\n')
        everylineactual = "','".join(everylineactual)
        everylineactual = f"'{everylineactual}'\n"
        with open('b.txt','a') as of:
            of.write(everylineactual)
```

Output file:

```
'1','2','3','4'
'5','6','7','8'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

```
    fwrite=open("b.txt","w")
    for line in open("a.txt"):
        fwrite.write("".join(["'" +str(char)+"'," for char in line.strip()]).rstrip("',")+"'\n")
    fwrite.close()
```

Produces the expected result